# How to compress a video to VVC(h266) or Versatile video Coding

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have a h264 video. I want to compress it to **Versatile Video Coding**(h266) by using **ffmpeg**. Can anyone tell me how to do it by using ffmpeg or any other way.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022-08-22 Gyan.dev win64 full build, VVC is not included with ffmpeg. This is probably due to licensing issues.

I cannot find any pre-built binaries for vvencapp. That likely means posting a redistributable vvencapp binary is not allowed at this time, again due to licensing issues. It seems to have the same problem as the Frauenhofer fdk-aac. You can build it for yourself, but you can't redistribute the binary.

You can build vvencapp from the Frauenhofer open source git
https://github.com/fraunhoferhhi/vvenc

Comment: It is odd because the repo show the license is BSD so free source/binary changed/original form is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

For version `ffmpeg version 2022-07-21-git-f7d510b33f-full_build-www.gyan.dev` I see it is supported. So probably you should update your version.

You can use command:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

to check the supported codecs